# Subclassing a control

Tags: windows, api

Ok so i'm trying to subclass a ListView control. I'm using SetWindowLong(). Consider this code:

WNDPROC oldProc;

WNDPROC newProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam) // not proper code, but you get the idea
{
  // some code here
}

MainProc(...)
{
  oldProc = SetWindowLong(control_hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG) &newproc);
}

At the setwindowlong function call, i'm getting a compiler error.
error: address of overloaded function with no contextual type information

Yet as MSDN, their example is pretty much the same. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the definition of `newProc` is incorrect. It should be:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK newProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    // Some code here.
}
```